# How to filter a queryset with another queryset to get a single value from a list of value in the former queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm currently working on a functionality in my web app, There is a form for users to upload images and when there's more than one images, i'm looping through the images to save each to the db.

The Property Model:

```
class PostProperty(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CategoryTypes.choices, default= CategoryTypes.FOR_RENT, max_length=50)
    category_type = models.ForeignKey(PropertyTypes,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then i have another model which is linked to the property model which allows users to upload images for the property on another page:

```
class PostPictures(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostProperty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pictures = models.ImageField(default='property_post.jpg', upload_to='images/')
```

Have created a view function, which gets the images from the form and compresses it, after compression, it loops through each and saves it to the db.

```
                    memory_upload = []
                    for x in range(len(images)):
                       img = images[x]
                       im = Image.open(img)
                       im_io = BytesIO()
                       if im.mode != 'RGB':
                          im = im.convert('RGB')
                       im = im.resize(img_res)
                       im.save(im_io, format= 'JPEG', optimize=True, quality=50)
                       memory_upload.append(InMemoryUploadedFile(im_io, None, img.name, 'image/jpeg', im_io.tell(), None ))

                    for items in memory_upload:
                       parser = PostPictures.objects.create(post = property, pictures = items)
                    parser.save()
                    return redirect('profile')
```

After the images are saved in the db. I want to create a view for the property list where the user can see all the properties they've posted with only a single image being returned out of the list of images for the property, how do i go about it?.

Answer (score 0):

I think have figured it out but might not be the best implementation, if you have a better implementation for it, i would appreciate your answer.

```
lister = PostProperty.objects.filter(poster = request.user)
pix = []
    for items in lister:
        pics = PostPictures.objects.filter(post__title = items) 
        pix.append(pics[0])

context = {
        'lister':lister,
        'pix':pix, 
        }
```

This pushes the first value of the iteration and it also carries the properties of the linked model with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can directly query this

```
PostPictures.objects.filter(post__poster=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything pythonic to get the first image in the queryset, you can access it with the `_set` reverse accessor:

```py
# in your views
listings = PostProperty.objects.filter(poster=request.user)
for listing in listings:
    post_picture = listing.postpictures_set.first()
    ...
```

```html
# in your template
{% for listing in listings %}
    {{ listing.postpictures_set.first.pictures }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you have named your model and one of the fields as `PostPictures` and `Pictures` respectively. It's better to use the singular rather than plural for model and field names, i.e. `PostPicture` and `Picture` - even if the intension is to have multiple pictures in your app.